Why is my Flutter app crashing on launch only in iOS release build?
I have a Flutter app that I just upgraded to Flutter 3.19.5, and spent the day upgrading certain packages and changing small styling pieces of the app. When I sent it off to TestFlight I realized that the test build was crashing immediately upon launch, and running with the --release flag locally I found the same.
I ran the app from Xcode and found this error when the app crashes:
"Assertion failed: (borrow == 0), function GRPC_ec_felem_neg, file felem.c, line 66."
This seems to be associated with BoringSSL, and the function the error references looks like this:
void ec_felem_neg(const EC_GROUP *group, EC_FELEM *out, const EC_FELEM *a) {
  // -a is zero if a is zero and p-a otherwise.
  BN_ULONG mask = ec_felem_non_zero_mask(group, a);
  BN_ULONG borrow = bn_sub_words(out->words, group->field.N.d, a->words,
                                 group->field.N.width);
  assert(borrow == 0);
  (void)borrow;
  for (int i = 0; i < group->field.N.width; i++) {
    out->words[i] &= mask;
  }
}

My Flutter doctor comes back with no issues whatsoever, and the Android release build works fine.
I have been uninstalling, upgrading, and changing packages and and deployment targets all day to no avail. No matter what happens, the app successfully builds, launches briefly, and then immediately crashes on the splash screen.

I have the same problem but on a native iOS app. After doing a research, I noticed that the problem appeared on the version 10.17 with Xcode 14. With Xcode 15 works like a charm.

Amazing, thanks! I just updated Xcode and the problem seems to have vanished.
